# Fixing error : The type com.mockobjects.MockObject cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, mockito

I am trying to learn unit testing of a servlet with mock objects, from a simple example. I copied all the example code and included what I think are the necessary jars into eclipse build path for my project. But, I still get the error: 'The type com.mockobjects.MockObject cannot be resolved. It 
is indirectly referenced from required .class files'

The jars are:

```
mockito-all-1.9.5-sources.jar
mockito-all-1.9.5.jar
mockobjects-jdk1.3-j2ee1.3-0.09.jar
servlet-api-2.5.jar
```

Temperature servlet:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

//Converts farenheit to celcius
public class TemperatureServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String str_f = req.getParameter("Fahrenheit");

        res.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();

        try {
            int temp_f = Integer.parseInt(str_f);
            double temp_c = (temp_f - 32) * 5.0 / 9.0;
            out.println("Fahrenheit: " + temp_f + ", Celsius: " + temp_c);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            out.println("Invalid temperature: " + str_f);
        }
    }
}
```

Tester class:

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;

import com.mockobjects.servlet.MockHttpServletRequest;
import com.mockobjects.servlet.MockHttpServletResponse;

public class TestTempServlet extends TestCase {

    public void test_bad_parameter() throws Exception {
        TemperatureServlet s = new TemperatureServlet();
        MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
        MockHttpServletResponse response = new MockHttpServletResponse();

        request.setupAddParameter("Fahrenheit", "boo!");
        response.setExpectedContentType("text/html");
        s.doGet(request, response);
        response.verify();
        assertEquals("Invalid temperature: boo!\n",
                response.getOutputStreamContents());
    }

    public void test_boil() throws Exception {
        TemperatureServlet s = new TemperatureServlet();
        MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
        MockHttpServletResponse response = new MockHttpServletResponse();

        request.setupAddParameter("Fahrenheit", "212");
        response.setExpectedContentType("text/html");
        s.doGet(request, response);
        response.verify();
        assertEquals("Fahrenheit: 212, Celsius: 100.0\n",
                response.getOutputStreamContents());
    }

}
```

Comment: @Jens - but i already have mockobjects all ver 1.9.5.

Comment: Why you import `mockobjects-jdk1.3-j2ee1.3-0.09.jar`? Can you add complete Stacktrace plz.

Comment: @Jens - that is a compiler error. there is no stack trace.

Comment: @Jens - removed it from build path. Now the error is `The import com.mockobjects cannot be resolved`

Comment: Yes was my fault. See my answer.

Comment: @Jens - I now have mock core, spring mock and servlet api jars only. I get errors like `The method setupAddParameter(String, String) is undefined for the type`. I am trying to remove these errors. Btw, my code is from a 2003 book. They probably changed all the api now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The book is  pragmatic unit testing with java and junit from 2003. So, a lot of its code might not work. Firstly, have only the following jars in your project:

```
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
servlet-api-2.5.jar
spring-core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-mock-2.08.jar
```

Use the edited code for the clasess as given below. Your code will pass all the tests. Also note that there is no reponse.verify method in the api, so its commented.

Servlet:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

//Converts farenheit to celcius
public class TemperatureServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String str_f = req.getParameter("Fahrenheit");

        res.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();

        try {
            int temp_f = Integer.parseInt(str_f);
            double temp_c = (temp_f - 32) * 5.0 / 9.0;
            out.print("Fahrenheit: " + temp_f + ", Celsius: " + temp_c);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            out.print("Invalid temperature: " + str_f);
        }
    }
}
```

Tester:

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;

import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletResponse;

public class TestTempServlet extends TestCase {

    public void test_bad_parameter() throws Exception {
        TemperatureServlet s = new TemperatureServlet();

        MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
        MockHttpServletResponse response = new MockHttpServletResponse();

        request.addParameter("Fahrenheit", "boo!");
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        s.doGet(request, response);
        //response.verify();//Method not in latest api.
        assertEquals("Invalid temperature: boo!",
                response.getContentAsString());
    }

    public void test_boil() throws Exception {
        TemperatureServlet s = new TemperatureServlet();
        MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
        MockHttpServletResponse response = new MockHttpServletResponse();

        request.addParameter("Fahrenheit", "212");
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        s.doGet(request, response);
        //response.verify();//Method not in latest api.
        assertEquals("Fahrenheit: 212, Celsius: 100.0",
                response.getContentAsString());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You miss the `mockobjects-core` jar. You have the `mockito-all.jar` not the mockobjects all ver 1.9.5

Add also `mockobjects-jdk1.4-j2ee1.3.jar` and remove mockobjects-jdk1.3-j2ee1.3-0.09.jar`

Answer (score 0):

By cleaning `mockito` repository and `spring-boot-test` repository from `.m2 repository` and then updating maven project (Alt+F5) solved my similar problem of `org.mockito.Answers; cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files`